# Auto increment column suddenlly changed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I have a table with an auto increment column, until last night everything was fine and this column was growing one by one, the last Id which it had was 205.

From today suddenly it starts Id's from 10195. What can cause this? Can shrink database cause this? I'm not sure if from web-hosting they do anything with my database but I wonder what can cause this.

Comment: Shrink? Please look at the documentation before posting.

Comment: You have to also understand that the identity is never guaranteed to increment one by one and if you write code assuming that, you will have problem. In addition to the answers on the duplicate, you need to understand that a transaction rollback causes gpas and I have seen gaps this size from rolling back a large import.